# Earliest Deviation from uniform distribution

Tags: uniform-distribution, histogram

How can I to compute the earliest deviation from a uniform distribution from a heavy tailed distribution.I find that one can do it as follows:

max_ix = np.argmax(np.cumsum(hist) - np.sum(hist)*bins[1:])

However I cannot understand why this is so? Is there another way of computing the point in my variable where I deviate from uniform?

ThanksI

Comment: @fblundun - since that question (from the same user) was closed without an answer, I would assume no

Comment: @Henry And that's because this is purely a programming question, which is not on topic here.